# How can I download Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express 2008

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-express, ssms

I installed visual studio 2010 ultimate and I am trying to download Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express 2008, cause it installed sql server express 2008, but the management studio didnt come with it..

I have got this version:

```
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8961
```

But when I try to download 2008, every version that I  download seems to be corrupt and wont download..

I have windows xp 3, and I want to download a 2008 version, that wont override my sql server express that came with visual studio 2010 ultimate..

it wont open those:
https://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displayLang=en&id=7593

cause whenever I try to extract it says the file cant open,,extraction failed

```
the filename directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean with corrupt and won't download, a quick test downloads things just fine.

Comment: -1 Not a coding question, sorry. Voted to close

Comment: it gives me this : the filename directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect

Comment: too late on closing..lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, a whole lot of people have had this problem for several years now.

There are several years (up to late 2011) of comments and discussion [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/8a5ff5b7-1098-41a5-b9a1-417f102ae441) which seem to resolve the problem.

And this [step-by-step article](http://www.asql.biz/Articoli/SQLX08/Art1_2.aspx) linked there may also help you.

This may be the key from that first article:

> The 2008 version of the Management Studio is not a stand alone installation and **can only be installed as part of the SQL Server 2008 Express with Tools or Advanced installation**.
>
> Like many others, I spent countless hours trying to figure out how to
>   install the Management Studio for SQL Server 2008 Express - Advanced
>   installation (same should apply to the w/ Tools version).  What
>   happened in my case was that I installed Visual Studio 2008 Express
>   and during that process a stripped down "Instance" of SQL Server 2008
>   was installed that did not include the Management Studio.  Through
>   much pain and torture I learned that the Management Studio can only be
>   installed during installation of the first instance. To delete that
>   first instance, you must go to "Add or Remove Programs" and remove
>   "Microsoft SQL Server 2008".  The removal process will only remove one
>   instance at a time and if you have installed more than one instance
>   you need to keep going until all instances have been removed and the
>   application completely disappears from the Add or Remove Programs"
>   dialog.  Note: You do not need to uninstall any of the other SQL
>   Server 2008 applications that also appear in the "Add or Remove
>   Programs" dialog.  Then go back through the install process as
>   follows: Double click on SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe to load the SQL Server
>   Installation Center and then go to Installation > New SQL Server
>   stand-alone installation.  Then proceed through all of the
>   installation steps until you get to “Feature Selection” and click on
>   “Select All” to toggle on all of the Shared Features, which should
>   include Management Tools - Basic.Continue the process from there and
>   you should be good to go.  Hopefully this will help others to avoid
>   much of the pain that many of us have already experienced.

Comment: I installed  the SQL server 2005 studio successfuly..can I integrate it with visual studio 2010 instead of the 2008 express edition it came with?

Comment: Sure, I think so. Give it a try. There's lots of new features in SQL 2008, though, that just might make it worth your while making this one last effort at installing it. You can run both 2005 and 2008 on your machine at the same time.

Comment: I am uninstalling the whole thing..then I am going to try your way. the studio 2005, fails to connect to the server for some reason